# How to Find Out What Version of JUnit Jenkins is Expecting

Tags: jenkins, junit

I am trying to configure my Jenkins project to display the results of a JUnit XML report. However, the Jenkins project throws the below error when trying to display the JUnit XML during the build.

```
Recording test results
ERROR: Publisher hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver aborted due to exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/tasks/junit/JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser.parseResult(JUnitParser.java:90)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.parse(JUnitResultArchiver.java:120)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.perform(JUnitResultArchiver.java:137)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:74)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:734)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:683)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1765)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have read that this error is possibly due to a mismatch between the JUnit version Jenkins is expecting and the version used by my project. How do I find out which version of JUnit Jenkins is expecting? Also, is there anything else that could cause the above error?

Answer (score 0):

Error is thrown by `JUnitResultArchiver`. It is a dependency of Junit plugin. Go into the Jenkins and look for the version of `JUnit Plugin`.Then look at source code of that particular version on project's github: https://github.com/jenkinsci/junit-plugin

After doing that, you will have the exact version that it requires.

Another reason why you are seeing this error is that you have a different compile and runtime classpaths.